# Multi Line Labels and an Image with UIStackView

Tags: ios, uistackview

I am trying to see if I can easily use a UIStackView to create multi line labels and also display an image.

Here are my current constraints. 
[image]

When I run it I get the following:

[image]

If I remove the imageview then the multi line works. Somehow UIImageView width and height is messing up everything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your stack view horizontal and embedded in a UITableView cell with another embedded vertical stack view inside of it? I think there's a lot of extra hands in the pot when you're laying out. I would likely try and lose the 2nd nested vertical stack and calculate the height of the cells instead.

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a UITableViewCell. Inside the cell I have a parent stackview. Inside the stackview I have another vertical stackview which contains the label. In the parent stackview I also have uiimageview. If I loose the vertical stackview then uilabels will not align vertically.

Comment: In my personal opinion, both of those stack views are unnecessary. I think you can accomplish what you want with layout constraints and add your subviews directly to the cell.

Comment: Yes! I was able to accomplish that easily without UIStackView. I just wanted to see if it was easier when using UIStackView or not. I guess not.

Answer (score 4):

`StackView` does not really work well with constraints, as they kind of destroy the purpose of stack views. Since the vertical inner `stackView` is inside a horizontal `stackView` with the `imageView`. When you give `imageView` hard constraints, in order to satisfy these constraints and keep the height & width values of `stackViews` at same level with `imageView` and inner `stackView`, the inner `stackView` cannot expand and it's height and you cannot get the behaviour you want. So as also mentioned in the comments, it is better to achieve your design without `stackViews`.

PS: I'm not saying stackViews cannot be used with constraints in their subViews. It can be done, and sometimes allow programmers to successfully achieve their goal, but you will always get debugger warnings due to conflicting constraints about the views with constraints inside a stackView.

Answer (score 3):

Change height and width of the imageView to give proper look and don't give fixed height for the stackview, only give top, bottom, leading and trailing. 
[image: Xcode Screenshot]

THis is how it will look like
[image: Screenshot]